# Prepping concrete floor for laminate

Tags: concrete, flooring, laminate

I'm getting laminate flooring fitted in my lounge, porch and toilet and need to prep the concrete floor before it goes down.

The living room was easy as it only had carpet down. The porch and toilet had ceramic tiles which we've now removed (including adhesive). The concern I have is that there is a 1mm difference in the level of the floor between the lounge and the porch/toilet. Is this too much of a height difference for the laminate flooring to be laid evenly?

Answer (score 1):

Each flooring manufacturer has specific guidelines for the amount of tolerance for their product. It varies, but it is usually something like 1/8" (2 mm+/-), using a 4' or 8' straightedge. If your condition is a little drop, not a gradual difference, I would grind it down to make the transition over a larger area, say 1-2 ft out, or get a little thinset and fill it a bit.

Comment: Sounds like good advice concrete is not that hard to grind a mm off with a hand grinder and proper cutter or abrasive , just very messy.